# Use Plugin Whenever One Exists?

Tags: plugins

I'm new to WP so I am not confident in my abilities yet. Is it safest to always install a plugin, when available, for whatever functionality I want (as opposed to coding it myself)?

For example, I would like the user to be able to filter the posts displayed by tags, category, etc. I have found the [search filter plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-filter/) that seems to be exactly what I want.

But I am also looking into how to code this functionality myself using [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts).

Former seems easy and safe, latter seems fun but difficult.

Comment: Never ever use `query_posts`, it breaks the main query object, rerun queries and is slow. It also breaks pagination. So **never ever** use it. You should use `pre_get_posts` or the `posts_*` filters to alter the main query to suit your needs. I would suggest you to tear the plugin apart and work through it systematically and learn how it works :-)

Answer (score 1):

Always, definitely not, there are plenty of bad plugins out there. If a plugin exists that does exactly what you want without too much overhead and seems to be well supported and popular it's probably a good idea to use it. If you are mostly out to learn though, it can be a good idea to start with the small stuff and learn. There are a plethora of tutorials for WP coding and you can probably find one that covers most of the basics for just about anything you can think of doing early on. It doesn't take long to find some functionality you want that isn't quite covered by a good plugin.